# Unable to initialise LiveLike chat in Vue 3, Failed to resolve component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm running into the following error when trying to initialise the [LiveLike Chat](https://docs.livelike.com/docs/web-chat).

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: livelike-chat

Stripped back view:

```
<template>
  <livelike-chat></livelike-chat>
</template>
<script>
  import LiveLike from "@livelike/engagementsdk";
  import { onMounted } from "vue";
  export default {
    setup() {
      onMounted(() => {
        let clientId = 'somelongclientidsuppliedbylivelike';
        LiveLike.init({ clientId });
      });
    }
  };
</script>
```

The livelike chat is supposed to initialise to a custom element, `<livelike-chat>`, the trouble is Vue sees that and tries to find the component livelike-chat. How do I "tell" Vue to ignore that element, its not a component but a tag reserved for LiveLike?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [`isCustomElement` config](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#iscustomelement) for this:

```js
// main.js
const app = createApp({})
app.config.isCustomElement = tag => tag === 'livelike-chat'
```